# Typescript Exception: TypeError: message.To.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have some code samples for sending an email through mailjet as follows, but I keep getting an error message saying 'Stack: TypeError: message.To.map is not a function'.

```
interface Message {
  From: Sender
  To: Recipient[]
  Subject: string
  TextContent: string
  HTMLContent: string
}

interface Sender {
  email: string
  emailAlias: string
}

interface Recipient {
  email: string
  emailAlias: string
}


const message = JSON.parse(queueMessage) as Message

const emailMessage = {
    To: message.To.map(t => {
      return {
        From: {
          Email: t.email,
          Name: t.emailAlias
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

I converted the string to Message object and am trying to convert to mailjet message json format, but i keep getting the error message.

Can anybody give me a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: `map` is available of Array prototype. Are you sure `message.To` is an array? I can see you typecasted it to `Message` but during runtime, is it what you're getting?

Comment: Yes, add a `console.log(message.To)`.

Comment: Also, you're not getting a TypeScript exception... TypeScript has compilation errors and JavaScript has exceptions.

Comment: This is what I see. {"To":"[{\"email\":\"example@hotmail.com\",\"emailAlias\":\"Tester1\"}]","From":"{\"email\":\"example@gmail.com\"}","Subject":"Hello World","TextContent":"This is just a testing email."}

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `queueMessage` does not have `To` defined, or it is not an array.

Comment: This should be a comment, except that it has already been said   in the comments

Comment: @JuanMendes Well, Kanishk Anand and I, answered within minutes of each other. So I doubt he made the comment when I opened this question and typed my response. Please, tell me what the answer to this question is?

Comment: Anything that starts with "most likely" is "most likely" a guess and should not be an answer, should be a comment. Also, if this is problem, this is a question that should be closed because the answer isn't going to help anyone else and Stack Overflow is for questions that are going to help other people, not just someone who "forgot" to debug